# Error al Usar fscanf() en c

Tags: c, archivo

Tengo un problema al usar la funcion `fscanf()`, Tengo este archivo de Texto llamado clientes.txt:

```
Pedro Pérez 7569984 1 500000 100000
Luisa García 8987565 1 1.500000 250000
Josefa Cardenas 1565988 1 2700000 580000
María González 5456748 0 850000 0
```

Use la funcion fscanf para asignar cada uno de los datos del archivo en una varible,y use un buble while para ver como funciona pero me devolvio esto:

```
Pedro PÚrez 7569984 1 500000
Luisa GarcÝa 8987565 1 1
.500000 250000 8987565 1 1
Josefa Cardenas 1565988 1 2700000
MarÝa Gonzßlez 5456748 0 850000
MarÝa Gonzßlez 5456748 0 850000
```

Se repiten algunos datos y otro no se de donde salen. el codigo que use fue este:

```
int main(){
    char nombre[15], apellido[15];
    int ci, estadoCuenta, monDisp, monDeu;
    FILE * F = fopen("clientes.txt","r");
    while (feof(F) == 0){
        fscanf(F, "%s %s %d %d %d %d", nombre, apellido, &ci, &estadoCuenta, &monDisp, &monDeu);
        printf("%s %s %d %d %d \n", nombre, apellido, ci, estadoCuenta, monDisp, monDeu);
    }
    fclose(F);
    return 0;
}
```

Agradeceria mucho que me ayudaran con esto.

Comment: El quinto dato de la segunda fila es un decimal, por lo que te recomiendo usar un `float` para obtener/representar dicho valor. Me refiero al valor `1.500000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La marca de formato `%d` lee **números enteros**, un número entero no tiene decimales, así que si durante la lectura encuentra algo que no pertenezca a un número entero (por ejemplo un punto decimal `.`) entonces dejará de leer.

Probablemente querías leer un número en coma flotante como tercer número de tu lista de números:

```
char nombre[15], apellido[15];
int ci, monDisp, monDeu;
float estadoCuenta; // Número en coma flotante.
fscanf(F, "%s %s %d %d %f %d", nombre, apellido, &ci, &estadoCuenta, &monDisp, &monDeu);
//                     ^^ <-- Número coma flotante --> ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Muchas gracias bro no me habia dado cuenta 